# MongoDB - AWS lambda serverless timeout after 6.01 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, mongoose, lambda, aws-lambda, serverless

In some of my routes the lambda function times out after 6 seconds when it is using an existing mongodb connection.

I am sure the function itself is not the issue as I have added lots of logs and it takes 0.1 seconds to finish but the lambda does not return anything for 6+ seconds. In most of the tutorials online the db connection is in the same folder as the lambda function but I have moved it out to its own package as I have 5+ endpoints.

This is the most basic endpoint that times out every now and then

```
module.exports.getAll = async (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  try {
    await databaseModels.db();
    const x = await databaseModels.items.model.find({});

    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(x)
    })
  } catch (error) {

    callback(error, {
      statusCode: 500,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(error)
    })
  }
};
```

This is my connect to database function which I call at the start of every lambda function

```
const url = ``

let isConnected;
module.exports = connectToDatabase = () => {
  if (isConnected) {
    console.log('=> using existing database connection');
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  console.log('=> using new database connection');
  return mongoose.connect(url).then(db => {
    isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
  });
};
```

In one of the turorials I found the author opened a connection for each request and closed it when the computation was done. Is this a good practice?